# No overload can be found for "ToInt32" and the following number of arguments: "0"

Tags: powershell, join

I am trying to write a password generator with gui in powershell. I wrote the gui first and the random password generation funktion seperately. When i fused my funktion and the program together i ended up with this error message:

```
    Für "ToInt32" und die folgende Argumenteanzahl kann keine Überladung gefunden 
    werden: "0".
    In C:\Users\sh\Desktop\Test Powershell PWG_01.ps1:130 Zeichen:5    
    +     $a = -join ($UpperCaseLetters +
    +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

It accured after i "fixed" an other error saying i can not convert an object to an int. The error was in line 59
My possibly wrong fix for that was to put an [int]before the $length:

```
    $ActionButton.Add_Click({Get-RandomPassword (([int]$length = 
    $Zeichen.SelectedIndex), $chkB1, $chkB2, $chkB3 )})
```

This is my complete code: I used 1 Image and an icon for my gui so if u want to recreate the error be sure to remove them from (my) line 6 & 10

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -a System.Drawing   #lädt die .NET-Erweiterungen für GUI   # -a  ist ein Kürzel oder -an

$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form # Fenster erstellen
$objForm.Text = "Password Manager Ultimate"
$objForm.Icon="C:\Users\sh\Desktop\PWMicon.ico" # Pfad für Icon
$objForm.Backcolor="white"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(600,700)
$objForm.BackgroundImageLayout = 2
$objForm.BackgroundImage =[System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile('C:\Users\sh\Desktop\schloss.jpg') # Pfad für bgimage

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label # Objektklasse "Label aus der Forms Assembly 
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,480)
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20)
$objLabel.Text = "Email Adresse hinzufügen"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel)

$objTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox # Eingabefeld
$objTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,500)
$objTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,20)
$objForm.Controls.Add($objTextBox)

$Description                     = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label             # Beschreibung Zeichenlänge
$Description.text                = "Zeichenlänge"
$Description.AutoSize            = $false
$Description.width               = 75
$Description.height              = 20
$Description.location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,120)
$objForm.Controls.Add($Description)

$Zeichen                     = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ComboBox 
$Zeichen.text                = ""
#$Zeichen.width               = 170
$Zeichen.autosize            = $true
# Add the items in the dropdown list
@(8..32) | ForEach-Object {[void] $Zeichen.Items.Add($_)}  ##
# Select the default value
$Zeichen.SelectedIndex       = 0
$Zeichen.location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,150)
$Zeichen.Font                = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
$Zeichen.Width = 45
$objForm.Controls.Add($Zeichen)

$txtHost = New-Object Windows.Forms.TextBox  # Ausgabefeld für generiertes PW
$txtHost.TabIndex = 0 # Tab order
$txtHost.Top = 150; $txtHost.Left = 200; $txtHost.Width = 200;
$txtHost.height              = 20
$txtHost.Text = $a
$objForm.Controls.Add($txtHost)

$ActionButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button # Generieren Button
# Die nächsten beiden Zeilen legen die Position und die Größe des Buttons fest
$ActionButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(262,120)
$ActionButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(76,23)
$ActionButton.Text = "Generieren"
$ActionButton.Name = "Generieren"
$ActionButton.DialogResult = "Cancel"
#Die folgende Zeile ordnet dem Click-Event die Schließen-Funktion für das Formular zu
$ActionButton.Add_Click({Get-RandomPassword (([int]$length = $Zeichen.SelectedIndex), $chkB1, $chkB2, $chkB3 )})
$objForm.Controls.Add($ActionButton)

$SaveButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button # Speichern Button
# Die nächsten beiden Zeilen legen die Position und die Größe des Buttons fest
$SaveButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(450,500)
$SaveButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$SaveButton.Text = "Speichern"
$SaveButton.Name = "Speichern"
$SaveButton.DialogResult = "Cancel"
#Die folgende Zeile ordnet dem Click-Event die Schließen-Funktion für das Formular zu
$SaveButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($SaveButton)

$chkB1 = New-Object Windows.Forms.checkbox
$chkB1.Left = 20; $chkB1.Width = 200; $chkB1.Top = 10
$chkB1.Text = "Groß - und Kleinbuchstaben"
$chkB1.Checked = $true
$chkB1.TabIndex = 2
$objForm.Controls.Add($chkB1)

$chkB2 = New-Object Windows.Forms.checkbox
$chkB2.Left = 20; $chkB2.Width = 200; $chkB2.Top = 35
$chkB2.Text = "mit Zahlen"
$chkB2.Checked = $true
$chkB2.TabIndex = 2
$objForm.Controls.Add($chkB2)

$chkB3 = New-Object Windows.Forms.checkbox
$chkB3.Left = 20; $chkB3.Width = 200; $chkB3.Top = 60
$chkB3.Text = "mit Zahlen und Sonderzeichen"
$chkB3.Checked = $false
$chkB3.TabIndex = 2
$objForm.Controls.Add($chkB3)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button # Schließen Button
# Die nächsten beiden Zeilen legen die Position und die Größe des Buttons fest
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(450,600)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Backcolor="yellow"
$CancelButton.Text = "Beenden"
$CancelButton.Name = "Beenden"
$CancelButton.DialogResult = "Cancel"
#Die folgende Zeile ordnet dem Click-Event die Schließen-Funktion für das Formular zu
$CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

# 2 Funktionen zum generieren des PW                      #Funktion1 : Chars  ##gb $chkB1.Checked  ##  $Zeichen.SelectedIndex ######################################
function Get-RandomPassword ($length, $chkB1, $chkB2, $chkB3){
    if ($chkB1){$UpperCaseLetters = (65..90)}
    else {$UpperCaseLetters = (97..122)}
    if ($chkB2){$NumbersZeroToNine = (48..57)}
    else {$NumbersZeroToNine = (97..122)}
    if ($chkB3){$SpecialCharacters = (58..64)}
    else {$SpecialCharacters = (97..122)}

    
    $a = -join ($UpperCaseLetters +
                $LowerCaseLetters +
                $NumbersZeroToNine +
                $SpecialCharacters  |
                Get-Random -Count $length.ToInt32() | % {[char]$_} )
                $a
                $a |clip
                return $a
    }
# Get-RandomPassword ($length)
# Funktion zum Prüfen des Benutzerkontos
function Test-Cred {
           
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([String])] 
       
    Param ( 
        [Parameter( 
            Mandatory = $false, 
            ValueFromPipeLine = $true, 
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true
        )] 
        [Alias( 
            'PSCredential'
        )] 
        [ValidateNotNull()] 
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]
        [System.Management.Automation.Credential()] 
        $Credentials
    )
    $Domain = $null
    $Root = $null
    $Username = $null
    $Password = $null
      
    If($Credentials -eq $null)
    {
        Try
        {
            $Credentials = Get-Credential "domain\$env:username" -ErrorAction Stop
        }
        Catch
        {
            $ErrorMsg = $_.Exception.Message
            Write-Warning "Failed to validate credentials: $ErrorMsg "
            Pause
            Break
        }
    }
      
    # Checking module
    Try
    {
        # Split username and password
        $Username = $credentials.username
        $Password = $credentials.GetNetworkCredential().password
  
        # Get Domain
        $Root = "LDAP://" + ([ADSI]'').distinguishedName
        $Domain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($Root,$UserName,$Password)
    }
    Catch
    {
        $_.Exception.Message
        Continue
    }
  
    If(!$domain)
    {
        Write-Warning "Ups.. Etwas ist schief gelaufen."
    }
    Else
    {
        If ($null -ne $domain.name) # Fehlerhinweis vscode null soll links stehen. jetzt ist es Angepasst
        {
            return "Authenticated"
        }
        Else
        {
            return "Not authenticated"
        }
    }
}  # Ende Einlogg Funktion

$CredCheck = 0
$Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials

$CredCheck = $Credentials  | Test-Cred togrund\$env:USERNAME    # einloggen # domain überprüfen später
Clear-Host
If($CredCheck -eq "Authenticated")
{
    [void] $objForm.ShowDialog((New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form -Property @{TopMost = $true })) # Fenster im Vordergrund anzeigen
}
else                                                                      #wenn pw inkorrekt
{
    Write-Warning "Login fehlgeschlagen"
    Break
}
```

Comment: At first glance: You don't want the `.SelectedIndex`, but the `.Text` of the combobox. Then, you call a function in PowerShell with the values separated by **spaces**, not commas, so try `$ActionButton.Add_Click({Get-RandomPassword  ([int]$Zeichen.Text) $chkB1 $chkB2 $chkB3 })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focusing only on the error and how to solve it, the Windows Forms code is completely irrelevant to the question and, for future note, you should only ask a specific question on a specific problem.

You're trying to call the [`ToInt32()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32?view=net-7.0#methods) without the `[IFormatProvider]` argument, and there is no `ToInt32()` method with **no (`0`) arguments**, hence the error.

[image: something]

It's also unclear why you're trying to do such thing. To simplify your function, and make it work properly:

```bash
function Get-RandomPassword {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [int] $Length,

        [Parameter()]
        [switch] $ChkB1,

        [Parameter()]
        [switch] $ChkB2,

        [Parameter()]
        [switch] $ChkB3
    )

    end {
        $charsToPwd = @(
            97..122
            if($chkB1.IsPresent) { 65..90 }
            if($chkB2.IsPresent) { 48..57 }
            if($chkB3.IsPresent) { 58..64 }
        ) | Get-Random -Count $Length

        $newPwd = [string]::new([char[]] $charsToPwd)
        Set-Clipboard -Value $newPwd
        $newPwd
    }
}
```

**Testing how it works:**

```bash
Get-RandomPassword -Length 20                      # wmndzheavfgjuxqblcrs
Get-RandomPassword -Length 20 -ChkB1               # XsVrdycpoHTlNvqjZhGn
Get-RandomPassword -Length 20 -ChkB2               # 3b84chjnx5zaflkyri19
Get-RandomPassword -Length 20 -ChkB3               # r?dox:v=pz@hmucnjf>y
Get-RandomPassword -Length 20 -ChkB1 -ChkB2 -ChkB3 # WLCxJ694jcdEhI=a8VP1
```

**Implementing it into your `.Add_Click` event:**

```bash
$ActionButton.Add_Click({
    $params = @{
        Length = $Zeichen.Text
        ChkB1  = $chkB1.Checked
        ChkB2  = $chkB2.Checked
        ChkB3  = $chkB3.Checked
    }
    Get-RandomPassword @params
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried it and it works now.